# SKU / item id confusiion

Tags: magento2

I`m entering our online store datbase, for each item i have a unique item id and a almost unique bar code, the bar code may change with new new stock for example a bag of corn flakes 500 grams may have one barcode , after  6 months they may come up with new packaging with a new bar code.

so when i enter products into magento, for SKU will i use the bar code or SKU? if its SKU where do i use the barcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, SKU is a unique identifier for a product which should remain unchanged as Magento uses SKU at many places in code as well as Database.

As you stated that you have a barcode value unique for each product but may change with new stock, I suggest you not to use it as an SKU. You should give your product a unique SKU and create a new product attribute to store barcode details.